# Waiting on asynchronous call not working with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used deferred to wait about two function to complete (they feed template and display the result) before feeding a select present in the template.

When a tab is displayed, i do.

```
var notAssociateContact = getNotAssociateContact();
var associateContact = getAssociateContact();

$.when(notAssociateContact, associateContact).then(assignLocationToSelector($("select[name=locationIds\\[\\]]")));

function getNotAssociateContact() {

    var deferred = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/rest/contacts/notassociatedto/" + $("#lodgerId").val(),
        success: function(data, status, jqXHR) {

            $("#lodgerContactAvailableDivTemplate").empty();
            if (data.length != 0) {
               $("#lodgerContactAvailableDivTemplate").append(templateLodgerContactAvailable(data));
                $('#lodgerContactAvailableTableResult').bootstrapTable();
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, status) {
            // error handler
            alert("error " + jqXHR + " -  " + status);
        }
    }).then(function(response) {
        // optional callback to handle this response 
    });
    return deferred;

}


function getAssociateContact() {
    var deferred = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/rest/lodgers/" + $("#lodgerId").val() + "/contacts",
        success: function(data, status, jqXHR) {
            $("#lodgerContactDivTemplate").empty();
            if (data.length != 0) {
                $("#lodgerContactDivTemplate").append(templateLodgerContact(data));
                $('#lodgerContactTableResult').bootstrapTable();
                //  $('#lodgerContactTableResult tr').bind("dblclick", null, contactReferenceSelectedRow);
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, status) {
            // error handler
            alert("error " + jqXHR + " -  " + status);
        }
    }).then(function(response) {
        // optional callback to handle this response 
    });
    return deferred;
}
```

I don't get any error, but the assignLocationToSelector don't same to runned.
Select is empty.

In console if i run

```
assignLocationToSelector($("select[name=locationIds\\[\\]]"));
```

Select is feeded correctly.

When i debug and arrive on $.when, i see then the two ajax call is pending...

So it's seem like there is a issue with the deferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$.when().then()` needs to be passed a function reference.  You are calling a function immediately and then passing that return result.  That executes the function immediately rather than allowing `$.when()` to call it later.

Change your `$.when()` statement from this:

```
$.when(notAssociateContact, associateContact).then(assignLocationToSelector($("select[name=locationIds\\[\\]]")));
```

to this:

```
$.when(notAssociateContact, associateContact).then(function() {   
   assignLocationToSelector($("select[name=locationIds\\[\\]]"));
});
```